# VBA + selenium find elements CSS alternative for XPath

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath

I am quite new to selenium but I am getting better and better...:)

I am making a scraper which extracts data from a website and saves it in an excel table.

The site's structure is horrible, there are no id's at all, all the classes are named identically, and besides of classes there are very few tags and attributes used.
The site is full of tables and I need only the information from one specific
 table. It is hard to find it as the order of the tables is changing daily.

The structure of the site looks like this:

```
<div class="table">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">
                    <strong>I NEED the bla bla from this table!</strong>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="even">
                <td>01</td>
                <td>bla bla</td>
                <td>bla bla</td>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td>02</td>
                <td>bla bla</td>
                <td>bla bla</td>

        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>

<div class="table">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">
                    <strong>I DON'T need this!</strong>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="even">
                <td>01</td>
                <td>bla bla</td>
                <td>bla bla</td>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td>02</td>
                <td>bla bla</td>
                <td>bla bla</td>

        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

Of course there are many other tables from which I do not need the data but their structure looks exactly the same.

So I need the data only from one table. The way I collect the relevant data is by searching for the string I need ("I need this") and then step back a few nodes and then again step into the tbody section where I can get finally the "bla bla" text.
I am doing this with the help of XPath in VBA and Selenium.
Here is my code:

```
Set my_Element = driver.FindElementsByXPath("(//th[strong='My text'])[1]/../../../tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
```

I have two questions:
1) Is there any way to get the same results with driver.FindElementByCss() command?
2) As you can see in my Xpath command I need to input the exact text, is there any way to use the 'contains' command? (I was not able to make it work :( )

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This Xpath finds table with th begining with "I NEED" and get all td after the 1st one

```
//table[.//th/strong[starts-with(.,"I NEED")]]/tbody/tr/td[position()>1]
```

result

```
Element='<td>bla bla</td>'
Element='<td>bla bla</td>'
Element='<td>bla bla</td>'
Element='<td>bla bla</td>'
```

Comment: Dear Spalsh58!
Thank you for your reply! Your solution is indeed more practical then my code. However in the post I asked for CSS selector alternative (instead of Xpath).
Thank you!

Comment: i answered to poiтt 2 :)

Comment: :) Yes, that is true! :) Thank you!